# MVC 3 Partialview for Create view using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

[image]I would like to be able to select a dropdownlist with numerical values and use the selected value to determine size of object list that would need to be added to the entity table. I have not been able to get the count to initialize the list. Also, I need to refresh the partialview every time a user select different item. Suppose if a user chose 3 at first and the partial contains three blocks of divs, but later change the selection to 1, the partial should have only one block. I have been trying different ways but no luck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is what I have been doing so far:
jQuery for ajax call:

```
$(function () {
    $('#drpSelect').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/EduKate/_Test',
            data: null,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").append(data);                    
            }
        });
        return false;    
    });
});
```

Dropdown:

```
    <select id="drpSelect">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
```

Target div in Create.cshtml file

```
    //some other html helpers for other properties ...
//where I want the partial
        <div id="result"></div>
```

PartialView: _Course.cshtml

```
@model List<EduKate.DataModel.Course>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="course">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.CourseID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.CourseID)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Credits)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.Credits)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.Title)
    </div>
}
```

ActionResult to render partial view on the Course view:

```
 public ActionResult _Test(int value)
    {            
        EdukateViewModel edukateViewModel = new EdukateViewModel();
        //
        for(int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            Course course = new Course();
            edukateViewModel.CourseList.Add(course);
        }
        return PartialView("_Course", edukateViewModel.CourseList);
    }
```

Get and Post method for Create Action

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EdukateViewModel edukateViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            //List<course> property in viewmodel is always null
            edukateRepository.Insert(edukateViewModel);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: (1) Is it not working at all? (2) Is `EduKate` the name of your *controller* or the name of your *whole app*? (3) `_Test` expects an `int` argument that you're not sending. Try appending the selected value at the AJAX URL, like `/EduKate/_Test/x`

Comment: (1) It is not working the way I want. I could strongly type my partial with an object and not the list and then I can add one row. (2) the controller is EduKateController (whole app is also EduKate). (3) You are correct, I was not sending selected value. I am adding url: '/EduKate/_Test/' + this.value and trying again (Thanks and +1 for that)

Comment: Nope. Please, give any feedback after that try

Comment: I would say it worked partially. I could get the count and add to the ViewModel courselist property. Problems - when I change the dropdown, it did not refreshed (div still had old rows). Another problem is after I fill up the form, on submit, the model's course list property is always null.  Please check the image on the question.

Comment: I dont see any form submission code.. am i missing something?

Comment: Here's the form submission code. It seems like since I could not update the viewmodel from on rendering partial, the list seems to be null:  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(EdukateViewModel edukateViewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                
                edukateRepository.Insert(edukateViewModel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

Comment: update the question please, also shouldnt the view or js mention this action.. show that part of the code too

Comment: I have updated the code with get and post actions

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the div did not update is the event bounds were lost since I think you replaced the entire div including the dropdown code.. use jquery `on' api to bind the events instead

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('change','#drpSelect',function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/EduKate/_Test',
            data: null,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").append(data);                    
            }
        });
        return false;    
    });
});
```